# Array of a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a Box class which holds a value and I want to create an array of this class.

Box Class:

```
public class Box<T> {
    public T t;
    public Box(T t){ this.t = t; }
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer>[] arr = new Box<Integer>[10];
    }
}
```

Compiler says :

> Cannot create a generic array of Box

I wonder that why we cant do that and how can I do that?

Comment: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not allow generic arrays.

You can find more info here: [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm).

For a quick fix, use [List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (or [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) instead of Array.

```
List<Box<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<Box<Integer>>();
```

Detailed explanation of the issue:
 [Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html):

Answer (score 1):

This used to work(generates a warning), should still do what you need:

```
 Box<Integer> arr = (Box<Integer>[]) new Box[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there are two possible workarounds:

- use an `ArrayList<Box<Integer>>`
- use reflection (but you will have warnings) through `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, length)`

Comment: There is no reason to use `Array.newInstance`. The component type is known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Box<Integer> arr = (Box<Integer>[])new Box<?>[10];
```